# Powershell export csv lost line breaks

Tags: powershell

I use the following ps command to batch read the contents of each txt file in the folder, and then export it to csv. It reads normally, but the file contents become one line, and all the newline characters are lost

`ls |Select-Object -Property {Get-Content $_.FullName -Encoding utf8} | Export-Csv "a.csv" -Encoding UTF8`

I want it to keep the format when I export it (mostly Spaces and newlines)

input and output : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8S9w.png)

Comment: is the file you read a csv? how is the structure?

Comment: You really do not want to preserve linefeeds in a CSV file. That's because there is no definite standard of CSV, and a lot of implementations simply consider a LF as row delimiter. Sure, RFC4180 suggests otherwise, but reality begs to differ. If you need to preserve newlines, use another a format.

Comment: Please show us some of the file you are using as input. (sanitized of course).

Comment: I added input and output at the end of the article, and its output is messy, missing the original line break

Comment: You are trying to convert CSS stylesheets as CSV files? What problem are you [trying to resolve](https://xyproblem.info/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Either: Use `-Raw` with [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) to ensure that each file is read *as a single, multi-line string*.

  ```
  # Note the use of -Raw
  Get-ChildItem |
    Select-Object -Property { Get-Content -Raw $_.FullName -Encoding utf8 } | 
    Export-Csv "a.csv" -Encoding UTF8
  ```
- Or, if you want to control the newline format and whether each file's lines should have a trailing newline, use `Get-Content` *without* `-Raw` and join the resulting *array* of lines with the newline character/sequence of choice using [`-join`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Join):

  ```
  # Note the -join "`n" (joining the lines with Unix-format LF-only newlines).     
  # Each resulting string will have *no* trailing newline, but you
  # you can add it with ((Get-Content ...) -join "`n") + "`n"
  # Use "`r`n" for Windows-format CRLF newlines.
  Get-ChildItem |
    Select-Object -Property { (Get-Content $_.FullName -Encoding utf8) -join "`n" } | 
    Export-Csv "a.csv" -Encoding UTF8
  ```

Note that your CSV file:

- will have *one* column, whose fields are `"..."`-enclosed multi-line strings.

  - Use something like `Select-Object Name, { ... }` to also include each file's *name*.
- that column's *name* will be the *verbatim content* of the [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ ... }` you're passing to [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object)'s `-Property` parameter.

  - To give the column a better name, use a [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) as the [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Calculated_Properties), whose `Name` entry allows you to specify the name, and whose `Expression` entry must be your script block; e.g.:

    ```
    ... |
    Select-Object @{ Name='FileContents'; Expression={ Get-Content -Raw $_.FullName -Encoding utf8 } } | ...
    ```

---

As for **what you tried**:

- When used without `-Raw`, `Get-Content` streams a file's content *line by line*, and when that output is *captured*, it becomes an *array*.
- What the script block of a calculated property evaluates to is used *as a whole* to determine that property's value, so an *array* of lines is indeed the result.
- When [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv) (or [`ConvertTo-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-csv)) encounter a property value that is an *array* (or a collection of similar type), it *stringifies* it, i.e. it must create a representation of the collection *as a single string*:

  - *Usually*, this results in *useless* stringification simply by the collection's *type name*, e.g., in the case of an array, *verbatim* `System.Object[]`
  - However, if - as in your case - the collection happens to be wrapped in a usually *invisible* `[psobject]` instance, a more helpful, albeit single-line stringification occurs: the (stringified) collection elements are joined *with spaces* in effect, the newlines from your file are therefore replaced with spaces.
  - The reason a `[psobject]` wrapper is present in your case is that PowerShell wraps output objects from a *pipeline* that way - which includes output from a script block (`{ ... }`).

To illustrate the above:

```
# NO [psobject] wrapper -> CSV serialization by *type name*:
PS> [pscustomobject] @{ ArrayProp = 'one', 'two' } | ConvertTo-Csv

"ArrayProp"
"System.Object[]"  # !!
```

```
# WITH [psobject] wrapper -> CSV serialization by 
# *space-concatenated elements*:
PS> [pscustomobject] @{ ArrayProp = [psobject] ('one', 'two') } | ConvertTo-Csv

"ArrayProp"
"one two"  # !!
```

Comment: Take a tumble, follow your solution to the operation, the problem is solved.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @LeiLi - please also see my update, which explains in detail what happened with your own attempt.